# Error setting SMTP deliveryMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, smtpclient

Hi this is a piece of code that send email from IIS but I got this error
**The value of the property 'deliveryMethod' cannot be parsed. The error is: SmtpDeliveryMethodTypeConverter cannot convert from System.String**

this is my code:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage  ("mostang1970@yahoo.com", "hadinematipartow@yahoo.com");
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Subject = "testing of mailing list";
message.Body = "hi hadi .this email is just for test.";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

and this is my web.config :

```
<system.net >
    <mailSettings >
      <smtp deliveryMethod="PickupDirectoryFromIis " >
        <network host ="localhost" port ="25" defaultCredentials ="true "/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
```

please help

Comment: Please change the title to reflect the issue you're trying to get addressed here.

Answer (score 5):

There's a space after `deliveryMethod="PickupDirectoryFromIis`, you might want to remove that.

Comment: I corrected that and got this error "Cannot get IIS pickup directory."

Comment: @user1292316 you forgot to set `PickupDirectoryLocation`

Comment: @user1292316 you set it before you use `smtpClient.Send(message);`. If you don't know how `PickupDirectoryLocation` works, then I suggest you just use `DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network` (you need to edit this deliverymethod inside the web.config)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've already got `PickupDirectoryFromIis` hard-coded in your application, I suspect you can just remove it from your config file and all will be well. The rogue spaces pointed out by Diamondo25 are probably the root cause, but you should only configure it in one place for clarity anyway - so I'd remove this setting from web.config, but remove the space from "true " for the credentials.

Comment: sry ... way too fast ... you are so right when pointing out the senseless config-entry (and the main advantage and/or idea behind configuration at one place) - but, for the sake of completeness: the real problem in here is the trailing space in the attribue-value of `deliveryMethod`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Was editing - yes, the space is a problem, but why include it twice in the first place? That will just lead to confusion if the two values ever diverge.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SMTP on the machine running IIS is not configured properly or it is not running at all. You might be able to see the emails you have sent in one of the Inetpub subfolder.

Id you set PickupDirectoryFromIis, it means local SMTP server will pickup these up and relay to another SMTP.